# Is there a way to enforce limited uniqueness on a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I was curious if something like this is possible, here's what I hoped to do:

Table with columns A, B, C, D

For each A + B, only allow one distinct value for C

Example (Allowed)
A: "foo"
B: "bar"
C: 7
D: 0

A: "foo"
B: "bar"
C: 7
D: 1

Example (Not allowed)
A: "foo"
B: "bar"
C: 7
D: 0

A: "foo"
B: "bar"
C: 8
D: 1

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean that for an A+ B there can be many rows, but they must all have the same C? You wouldn't want this, because it violates database normalization. Create another table with A + B as the key and C as their attribute.

Comment: That's correct. This is a legacy table that's accessed by dozens of different applications so normalization will be high effort, was hoping for an alternative - sounds like there isn't. Thank you

Comment: You can still create the ABC table and fill it with a trigger. When updating your original table or inserting into it, your trigger will update / insert into the ABC table, too. If the ABC's key A+B gets violated by this, the whole statement will fail.

Comment: You can create an indexed view grouping by `A,B,C` and create a unique clustered index on that with key columns `A,B`

Comment: Thank you both for the ideas, will mark either as answer if you post below

Answer (score 2):

Move C to a separate table containing only A, B, and C, and make A+B a unique key.